# How do you use Web Workers with Webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, web-worker

I've been struggling to find the best way to use Web Workers while utilizing Webpack 5 and typescript. I try to follow the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/#example), however, when I try to create a Web Worker, I am experiencing the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Worker constructor: Failed to load worker script at "d:\Project\SeamCarving\js\dist0.bundle.js"
```

I am not sure why it is trying to access the file from my local system instead of through the development server like: `http://localhost:8080/js/dist0.bundle.js`.

Here's the code:

```
if (window.Worker) {
    let worker = new Worker(new URL("./image-worker", import.meta.url));

    worker.onmessage = function (message) {
      return receiveMessage(message);
    };

    worker.onerror = function (message) {
      console.log("ERROR: ", message.error);
      console.log(message.message, message.filename, message.lineno);
    };
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './js/main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js')
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './'),
    publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '/js/dist/'),
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "js/dist/"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/dist'),
  }
}
```

All resources I have found so far are using `worker-loader`, but it's my understanding Webpack 5 makes this obsolete.

View the full project on [GitHub](https://github.com/quinnzipse/WebSeamCarver/tree/working_the_web).

Comment: give the worker-loader a try even on V 5  import Worker from "worker-loader!./$Path

Comment: @RobertRowntree Thank you for the suggestion but, I really want to avoid using loaders in this case since they aren't needed in Webpack 5 as written in the [official documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers).

Comment: @Quinn how do you got it working with ts_loader, because i cam getting an error new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url)); in this line while bundling and it says additional loader may be needed. i can make it work with webpack-loader and webpack 4. How can i move to webpack5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out my problem,

**Incorrect** output block:

```
output: {
    publicPath: path.resolve(__dirname, "js/dist/"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/dist'),
}
```

`publicPath` in this case is set to use an absolute path. So, when I tried running it through the server it would serve as a `file://` instead of through `http://`. Since Chrome (and I believe most modern browsers) don't allow you to load local files as scripts for security reasons, it was blocking it.

Originally, I thought it may have been some sort of problem with using typescript, however, I learned it was just a misconfiguration causing the script to always use the absolute value.

**Corrected** output block:

```
output: {
    publicPath: "js/dist/",
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/dist'),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the issue after I upgraded my project from angular 12 to angular 13(including webpack upgradation from webpack 4 to webpack 5).

//Before upgrade

```
import * as testworker from 'worker-loader!./test.worker.bundle.js';
```

// After upgrade to webpack 5

```
const testworker = new Worker(new URL("test.worker.bundle.js", import.meta.url));
```

I had to change as mentioned above after upgrade to webpack 5 to make ng build successful. But when we run command of ng serve getting **runtime** error
with '***DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at** 'file::/// Path to js file' 'http://localhost: test.worker.bundle.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://localhost:4200'.

I tried adjusting output block in config file as well. None of them is solving the issue.

Let me know if anywhere else has to be changed.