# Webpack (w/ Angular) doesn't bundle a new Worker(): Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///...' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://...'

Tags: angular, webpack

I use pdfjs-dist, from version 2 to 3 they changed their webpack integration used to load their worker, and use the `new Worker()` syntax that Webpack 5 [is supposed to support](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers). Before they used worker-loader and it worked fine, now it doesn't.

The contents of the library looks like this:

```
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerPort = new Worker(
  new URL("./build/pdf.worker.js", import.meta.url)
);
```

Now, I tried this with hand-made files too in my own project, with the same result (so the library is not at fault), the problem being:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///myprojectpath/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://localhost:9003'.
```

Upon further examination it appears to me that Webpack doesn't bundle or transform anything. For example `import.meta.url` is an absolute local path to the file loading the worker, and no worker chunk is emitted either.

I use Angular and I suspect it may be to blame here since they seem to have a custom way to handle webworkers. But I don't *know* if that's right or why.

The only similar question (non-Angular) I found is this : [How do you use Web Workers with Webpack 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66710729/how-do-you-use-web-workers-with-webpack-5)
But logging the Webpack configuration produced by Angular shows that my `output.publicPath` value is `''` which therefore seems right according to the aforementioned post.

So does anybody knows why Webpack ignores my `new Worker` constructs and if it's an Angular thing?